# What is reflected in the Mirrorball?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Legendary Wizard Source [Mirrorball](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/mirrorball) is reflecting *something*, but I can't tell what it is. I wouldn't be surprised if it was an Easter Egg of some sort. Does anyone know what it is that the Mirrorball is reflecting?

Comment: Maybe you could look in the texture files for the mirrorball reflection?

Answer (score -2):

It is hard to tell exactly what it is, but it looks like a light house by the shore, similar to this image: [image]